# How to measure the time when a packet arrives?

Tags: linux, tcp

When the packet arrives the NIC generates an interrupt and the kernel then takes over. I want to measure the time at which a packet of a particular TCP flow arrives.

How do I do this in Linux? This what tools like tcpdump do.

Comment: JFTR i would start to look into systemta - have a look at the [sample scripts](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/keyword-index.html) e.g http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/network/netdev.stp

Answer (score 2):

`tcpdump` timestamps all the packets. So you should be able use tcpdump. Otherwise you could try wireshark, which also monitors network trafic, but with a nice and powerfull GUI. If you don't need to script this process, I would say Wireshark is your friend in this situation.

You can take a peek at http://www.howtogeek.com/104278/how-to-use-wireshark-to-capture-filter-and-inspect-packets/ for more info on how to use Wireshark.

If you are more interested in how to measure this yourself you could either inspect `tcpdump` with `strace` or, as suggested, read the source. `strace` will gives you a list of system calls that you can use in your own application. The easiest solution however, would be to run `tcpdump`, and then filter the output through `awk` or some other tool capable of filtering out the timestamp column.

Also, you can find more information about how to use `tcpdump` on http://danielmiessler.com/study/tcpdump/

Comment: I want to know how tcpdump does it

Comment: So read the [source](http://www.tcpdump.org/) and ask if you have questions about it

Comment: expanded answer with some words about the internals

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at tcptrack tool. You might be able to measure this.

Comment: I don't see how. Tcptrack displays connection statistics, not per-packet processing information.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like `traceroute`? The `-p` option permit to choose the protocol.

```
[root@osgiliath ~]# traceroute myserver.mydomain.com -p 443
traceroute to myserver.mydomain.com (10.11.20.30), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.119.9.253 (10.10.10.1)  0.262 ms  0.294 ms  0.360 ms
 2  10.111.225.114 (10.11.20.14)  0.326 ms  0.387 ms  0.466 ms
 3  myserver.mydomain.com (10.11.20.30)  7.558 ms  7.558 ms  7.547 ms
```